# How to extend type of $options property?

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I want to make the `$options` property of Vue instance well typed as possible. By default, this property typed as object `ComponentOptions<Vue>` with `string` keys and `any` values.

I want to replace `any` with my custom type `GenericOption`. I trying to extend `$options` via modules augmentation according to the official Vue documentation, but it fails.

```
import Vue from 'vue';

type GenericOption = {
  key: string,
  value: string // only for testing purpose
}

declare module 'vue/types/vue' {
  interface Vue {
    readonly $options: GenericOption
  }
}
```

I expect that `$options` will overriden and extended, but got following error:

> Subsequent property declarations must have the same type. Property
>   '$options' must be of type 'ComponentOptions,
>   DefaultMethods, DefaultComputed, PropsDefinition>, Record>', but here has type 'GenericOption'

Any suggestions?